# I print these values into a list in React, why isn't it styled like a list

Tags: html, reactjs, list, appendchild

```
    import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import axios from "axios";

const BASEURL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";


function axiosTest() {
    return axios.get(BASEURL).then(response => response.data)
}


function stepTwo(){
axiosTest()
        .then(data =>{
           
           for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
 console.log(data[i].name);
 let nameElm = document.createElement("li");
 let nameText = document.createTextNode(data[i].name);
  let name2use = nameElm.appendChild(nameText)
 document.getElementById("list4names").appendChild(name2use);

}
        })
    }

stepTwo();
function Component1(){

return(
    <div>
    <ol id = "list4names"></ol>
        </div>
    )


}


const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(<Component1 />);
```

So, this program successful prints out all the times taken from the axios request.  But what's strange is that even though I put them in an "ol" element with an "li" tag, they don't print in the style of a list.  They all print on a single line, no bullets, no spaces between the items even.  Why is this?  I tried putting them in the div as p tags too, but there were similar (albeit not identical) results.

Answer (score -1):

You're not appending the `li` that you've created to you're list; you're appending a `textNode`.

```
 let nameElm = document.createElement("li");
 let nameText = document.createTextNode(data[i].name);
 let name2use = nameElm.appendChild(nameText) // name2use is the appended textNode
 document.getElementById("list4names").appendChild(name2use); // this appends a textNode to your list, not the li
```

`nameElm.appendChild(nameText)` appends the `nameText` `textNode` to `nameElm` and returns the newly appended node (the `textNode` `nameText` in this case).

You want to append `nameElm`, the `li` you have created, to your list instead:

```
 let nameElm = document.createElement("li");
 let nameText = document.createTextNode(data[i].name);
 nameElm.appendChild(nameText); // append the textNode to the li
 document.getElementById("list4names").appendChild(nameElm); // append the li to the list
```